# how to apply lapply() with a function with arguments

Tags: r, apply, data-manipulation

I have this df:

```
set.seed(20)
df <- data.frame(X1 = sample(c(1:10,NA), 10, replace=TRUE),
                X2 = sample(c(1:10,NA), 10, replace=TRUE),
                X3 = sample(c(1:10,NA), 10, replace=TRUE),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> df
   X1 X2 X3
1  10  8  6
2   9  9  1
3   4  1  5
4   6  9  1
5  NA  3  3
6  NA  5  1
7   2  4 10
8   1  2 NA
9   4  4  1
10  5 10  8
```

Where I can use this functions easy:

```
lapply(df, sum)
df %>% lapply(., sum)
df %>% lapply(., as.numeric)
```

However, if I want to put `na.rm=TRUE` argument in `sum()` is impossible. I have been looking for an answer and it seems the only solution is to define the function sum inside `lapply()`, like:

```
lapply(df, function() {})
```

Is it really no possible to put the arguments of the function FUN inside `lapply`? Also, the problem I'm struggling with is when I want to apply a function which needs the data (for example, `sum(data, na.rm=TRUE)`) using pipe operators I cant give the data to the function as:

```
df %>% lapply(., sum(, na.rm=TRUE)) # It needs the sum argument.
df %>% lapply(., sum(., na.rm=TRUE)) # but I'm not looking to sum the whole df
```

Comment: Try `lapply(x, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Since you're using `dlyr` already. Why not use `df %>% summarise_all(sum,na.rm=T)`? No need to pipe to a lapply statement

Comment: Chris, I meant to use `lapply` directly, not under pipe. Check my answer below. And, @Julian_Hn, you made a typo of `dlyr` instead of `dplyr`. Please correct it.

Comment: Because I'm not looking to summarize, the sum is just part of the reproducible example. The question is how to apply `lapply()` with a function with its arguments. What I want to do is to transform some (mess) datetime characters in strptime() with localtimezone. However, the problem I'm having is just the argument inside lapply.

Comment: You can do it with any function. Suppose the function is `f` with two arguments `x` and `y`. You want to use `lapply` on `x` argument on `df`, keeping `y` fixed at `k`. Then try `lapply(df, f, y = k)`

Comment: Are you looking for `lapply(df, function(x) {sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)})`? This is the same as yarnabrina's suggestion except you can see how you might customize the function being applied.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to sum the columns of `df` here. You can do it as below:

```r
set.seed(seed = 20)

df <- data.frame(X1 = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 X2 = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10, replace = TRUE),
                 X3 = sample(c(1:10, NA), 10, replace = TRUE))

df
#>    X1 X2 X3
#> 1  10  8  6
#> 2   9  9  1
#> 3   4  1  5
#> 4   6  9  1
#> 5  NA  3  3
#> 6  NA  5  1
#> 7   2  4 10
#> 8   1  2 NA
#> 9   4  4  1
#> 10  5 10  8

lapply(df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
#> $X1
#> [1] 41
#> 
#> $X2
#> [1] 55
#> 
#> $X3
#> [1] 36
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

An alternative will be to use `colSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: ... or `sapply(df, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: I don't understand. It's supposed that `na.rm` argument is from the `sum` function and `lapply()` `FUN` arguments are supposed to be different functions. How `lapply` knows that `na.rm=TRUE` is for `sum`?

Comment: The complete syntax is `lapply(df, function(i)sum(i, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: @Chris Please go through the documentation of `lapply`. It's used in the form `lapply(X, FUN, ...)`, where the documentation says `... optional arguments to FUN.`

Comment: Or you can use the `...` combined with `na.rm` inside the function to call e.g.  `lapply(df, function(...) sum(..., na.rm=TRUE))`.